# R loop for applying an equation to each unique category

Tags: r, loops, stat, genetics

I am seeking help in writing an R loop to calculate the shannon's information content (SIC)
for every unique haplotype. The data includes the haplotypes in column 1 and frequency of haplotypes in column 2. As you can see in the example data with just 4 unique haplotypes, there are different numbers of each haplotype, with a frequency corresponding to each one. The frequency for all haplotype H* sums up to 1. The equation for SIC is

Σi (πhi*log(1/(πhi)))

where πhi is the frequency of the hi haplotype

[image: SIC Equation]

```
Haplotype   Frequency
H1  0.8278
H1  0.02248
H1  0.1494
H2  0.8238
H2  0.02248
H2  0.1497
H3  0.1497
H3  0.02248
H3  0.8244
H4  0.628
H4  0.02248
H4  0.1483
H4  0.1637
H4  0.01081
H4  0.01798
```

In this example, the SIC for H1 would be

(π*0.8278*log(1/(π*0.8278))) + (π*0.02248*log(1/(π*0.02248))) + (π*0.1494*log(1/(π*0.1494)))

and the final output should give 4 SIC values, one corresponding to each unique haplotype.

I believe using `lapply()` is the correct method of going foward, but my R skills are very elementary to know what to do next. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`aggregate`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html):

```
result <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Haplotype), function (h) sic(h[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have the code written as:  <br/> 

    sic <- function(p)
{
sum(log2(1/p)*p)
}  <br/> 

    result <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Haplotype),function(h)sic(h[2]))  <br/> 

but it is giving the message:

Error in 1/p : non-numeric argument to binary operator   <br/>

I believe the code after 'function' is incorrect. Do I need this if I am designating 'sic' already as a function?

Comment: I simplified slightly – but my code *does* work. The only problem is that it also tries to apply the transformation to the `Haplotype` column which you obviously don’t want. However, this gives me a warning, not your error.

Comment: Ok I believe I'm getting the same warning as you now "In Ops.factor(log2(1/p), p) : / not meaningful for factors". So I just need to direct the function to the Frequency column instead. Can I ask what the "sic(h[2])" part of the code is doing? Is it telling R to direct the function "sic" towards column 2 of the dataset?

Comment: I think I wrote an alternative that works as well: "result <- aggregate(frq$Frequency~frq$Haplotype, data=frq,FUN=sic)" this seems to have done the trick, thanks!

Comment: @user2895292 In answer to your question: yes, precisely. And your second comment does look more promising. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df1,.(Haplotype),summarize,mysum=sum(pi*Frequency*log(1/(pi*Frequency))))
  Haplotype      mysum
1        H1 -1.9433259
2        H2 -1.9190102
3        H3 -1.9226882
4        H4 -0.1784109

library(data.table)
dt1<-data.table(df1)
dt1[,list(sum=sum(pi*Frequency*log(1/(pi*Frequency)))),by=Haplotype]
   Haplotype        sum
1:        H1 -1.9433259
2:        H2 -1.9190102
3:        H3 -1.9226882
4:        H4 -0.1784109
```

Comment: Thank you for those codes; they yielded the same results as "result <- aggregate(frq$Frequency~frq$Haplotype, data=frq,FUN=sic)", thus confirming that these work :D